# NextJS Image component with CloudFrontSigned Cookies

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, nextjs-image

I am using AWS Cloudfront and I am restricting access to the content using Signed Cookies. The whole procedure works fine and I am able to load the imaged into the NextJS app if I use the following snippet

```
<picture>
  <img src={fileScreenshotUrl} alt={file.Alt?? "No alt text"} />
</picture>
```

When I try to use

```
 <Image
     src={fileScreenshotUrl}
     width={100}
     height={100}
     alt={file.Alt?? "No alt text"}
/>
```

I get error 403, am guessing NextJS tries to load the image server side without including the appropriate cookies for cloudfront to allow access.

How can achieve that?

Comment: check your image path...  because it ok

Comment: What do you mean is ok? Does NextJS component Image run on server side as i assumed? if yes do you know if it attached cookies when making the request to CloudFront? The fact that one code snippet says source and the other fileScreenshotUrl is just copy-paste. I fixed it

Comment: whenever the whole procedure works fine, that means you are not given the right path to the image.
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#src This document tells multiple things about **image src **.  statically imported image, absolute external URL, or an internal path etc